# Vim: Change color of window counter in tab line

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How do you change the color of the window counter that VIM displays in the tab bar. I'm familiar with how to set highlighting on groups, what group applies to it? Below is an image of a vim session, where the current tab has two splits, with the nefarious pink window counter.

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the characteristic default color (and some experiments), this is the `Title` highlight group. Note that this is also used in several Ex commands (e.g. `:changes`). If you don't want that color, you can also define your own, custom tabline. See `:help setting-tabline` for an example that emulates the default one.